# Looping over object entries and displaying list of data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display all entries that exist (excluding loss) under 'test'. I've managed to return the first item on the list but cannot get the remaining. The diagram below shows what I am displaying on the front end and what my file has in it for that specific entry (on the right). The data coming back in 'test' can vary for each array item. Appreciate any help.

[image]

```
  const getMetrics = (model) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(model.test)) {
      if (key !== 'loss') {
        // console.log(key, value);
        return key + value;
      }
    }
  };

  .map((i) => {
    const model = i.models[Object.keys(i.models)[0]];

    return (
       {getMetrics(model)}
    )
 })
```

Comment: Could you add the exact format you are expecting as an output, given your input ? That would help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getMetrics` function will always return the first element matching the condition. Here you can change your function to rely on higher order functions like `map` and `filter` to do your task like so :-

```js
const model = {
  test: {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3,
    loss: 4
  }
}

const getMetrics = (model) => {
  return Object.entries(model.test).filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'loss').map(([key, value]) => key + value);
}

console.log(getMetrics(model));
```